# removing duplicates in multiple inheritance(with diamond inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

I am trying to do a diamond inheritance problem with class `P` inheriting from `N`, and `O`, and classes `N`, and `O` inheriting from `M`.

```
  M
 / \
N   O
 \ /
  P
```

**Header**

```cpp
class M {
   public:
    M();

    M(int aVal);

    int a;
};

class N : virtual public M {
   public:
    N();

    N(int aVal, int bVal);

    void foo();

    int b;
};

class O : virtual public M {
   public:
    O();

    O(int aVal, int cVal);

    void foo();

    int c;
};

class P : public N, public O {
   public:
    P();

    P(int aVal, int bVal, int cVal, int dVal);

    void foo();

    int d;
};
```

I want to create a specialised constructor to initialise the 4 values without any duplicates.

**Source code**

```cpp
P::P(int aVal, int bVal, int cVal, int dVal)
: N(aVal, bVal), O(aVal, cVal), d(dVal)
{       
    // Only initialize with initializer list    
}
```

But `aVal` is initialised by both `N` and `O` constructor.
Any ideas how to fix this??
If any more code is required I will provide.

Comment: Remove the default constructor of `M` and notice how the `P` constructor does not compile anymore. That is because the most-derived class gets to initialize virtual base classes. As written, `P` uses `M`'s default constructor. `N` and `O` skip the `M` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> But a is initialised by both N and O constructor

This assumption is incorrect. If virtual inheritance worked like this, it would not solve diamond problem (1 constructor call = 1 object created, if both `N` and `O` called constructor of `M`, you would have 2 `M` objects, like without virtual inheritance).

Instead, `virtual` base classes are always initialized by the most derived class, in this case `P`. Since you do not specify initialization of `M` in `P` constructor, default constructor is used. To use parameterized constructor, specify it in member initializer list:

```
P::P(int aVal, int bVal, int cVal, int dVal): M(aVal), N(aVal,bVal), O(aVal,cVal), d(dVal)
{
}
```

Note that `aVal` in `N` and `O` may be unused. You might want to refactor code to include the fact that you are using virtual inheritance and remove those parameters (or add separate constructors without them if you are going to use `N` or `O` directly).